# MySQL : Count row where sum of left day is less than 30

Tags: mysql, date, count, sum, row

I want to count the users in the table who's subscriptions are going to expire within a month (30 days). Here is my code:

**user_db**

```
id         name        exp_date
1          John        2013-03-01
2          Alice       2013-02-25
3          Ken         2013-01-10
4          Elise       2013-04-11
5          Bruce       2013-03-14
```

According to the DB above. There should be 3 persons whom their subscription is about to be expired - John, Alice and Bruce. **I don't want Ken to be counted** because he doesn't want to subscribe for more.

Here's my MySQL code:

```
SELECT count(id) AS exp_pax, 
       datediff(exp_date,now()) AS day_left 
FROM labour_db 
WHERE day_left<=30
```

Well, the code does selects only a row in which the sum of day less than 30 but it doesn't count. So please you guy suggest me.

Regards,

Comment: *because he doesn't want to subscribe for more* -- how do you know that?

Comment: @JW, if he does. The subscription date shouldn't be less than today, should it?

Comment: ok, see my answer below. you need to check for the `exp_date`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to count all records where (1) the expiration date is within 30 days of now and (2) the expiration date is not before now, then use

```
SELECT count(*) AS exp_pax 
FROM   user_db 
WHERE exp_date<=timestampadd(day, 30, now())
       AND exp_date >= now();
```

Answer (score 1):

If that's the case then you need to add condition wherein it checks if the `exp_date` is less than today.

```
SELECT  COUNT(*) totalCount
FROM    user_db 
where   exp_date <= timestampadd(day, 30, now()) AND
        exp_date > NOW()
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/54c03/9)

Comment: JW, your code is also work, absolutely as brilliant as D Mac does. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `group by id` to get your count.

Count will roll up rows, as you expect, but when combined with a `group by` clause, will count each "group". You could use this usefully, for instance, to group by expiration date.

Comment: Joseph, Yes it does count but also include the expired date as well which I don't want them to be counted.

Comment: @Wilf, you have to tell us how you can determine that Ken isn't supposed to be counted. Then we can translate that into SQL for you.

Comment: @DMac, Just only the exp_date where datediff from today is less than 30 and not negative.